# По какому url нужно перейти чтобы найти страницу / шаблон?

Tags: python, django

Вот сам шаблон **index**:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Первый шаблон</title>
</head>
<body>    
    Ну как тебе?
</body>
</html>
```

Вот **views**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.http import HttpResponse
#from django.template import loader

#from .models import Question

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html'),
```

Comment: Поищите переменную-список `urlpatterns` там пишут пути к view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 1):

В файле urls.py добавьте в urlpatterns следующее

```py
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

После чего на сайте по запросу страницы '/' будет отображён ваш шаблон
Подробнее можно почитать тут: https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

В urls.py вы создаёте пути. Там и ищите. Если вы хотите допустим в шаблоне сделать ссылку, то это будет выглядеть так: {% url 'псевдоним ссылки' %}, псевдоним ссылки это 3 аргумент функции path - name,его и пишите к примеру:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),#name='index' - псевдоним ссылки
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html'),
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Первый шаблон</title>
</head>
<body>    
    Ну как тебе?
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">ссылка на эту же страницу</a>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S Тут я уже более подробно рассказал, знаю, что вопрос немного другой, но пусть это будет на будущее! Зато всё понятно:)

Comment: ваше решение не помогло, но я блогадарен

Comment: А что вам надо? Опишите по конкретнее и это было не решение,а пример с обьяснением,но видимо я не понял,что вам нужно